# How to start Apple hardware test on Catalina OS?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, catalina, apple-hardware-test

I need to check something (answer below)

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/374656/207453

and I would like to run the Apple Hardware Test. As far as I know in order to get this menu I need a moment when I turn my Macbook on hold <kbd>D</kbd> button or <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (actually I have the same result on my Macbook).

The first image that I saw was this one

[image]

Then I was asked to choose Wifi and fill in the password and after a few moments I got such message

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Feel free to ask

Comment: If you have another Mac, you may want to try running Apple Hardware Test via USB as explained in this GitHub page: https://github.com/upekkha/AppleHardwareTest